# How to authenticate that a POST comes from the right source?

Tags: security, post, https, token

I have a logged in user in one system and I want to enable that user to use another system. The source system is supposed to send a POST request to the target system containing various parameters. The target system should be able to authenticate that the POST request comes from the right source and only then let the user in.

The communication is done via HTTPS.

Would it be enough to have a passphrase stored in both systems, then take the current date + the user id, encrypt it using the passphrase and send the encrypted string as a parameter? The target system could use the passphrase to decrypt it and check if it is a valid date (not too old) and a known user id. If so, the source system is correct and access is granted.

Encryption could be done using SHA-1, MD5, etc.

For example:
2017-09-06-USER123 -> encrypt(passphrase) -> wrgengrhwhrghewrw98tg7r7gw
wrgengrhwhrghewrw98tg7r7gw -> decrypt(passphrase) -> 2017-09-06-USER123

I'm not very familiar with security issues and possible attacks, but using HTTPS and a generated token that changes daily and is based on the user sounds rather safe to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a DB table to store session data. If the session id is related to the login information, you will be able to control who goes where and does what.

It's important to watch out for "session jacking" though. Make sure there is a regeneration time that re-authenticates the user every so often.